# How to execute subscribe block before other methods in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, observable

In my service class, I have two string arrays that I'm trying to fill with data from HTTP get request with the following code:

```
keys: string[];
values: string[];

constructor(private entityDetailsService: LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) {
    this.getEntityDetails().subscribe(data => {
        this.keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
        this.values = Object.values(data[0]);

        console.log("inside subscribe: keys: " + this.keys + ", values: " + this.values);
    });
    console.log("outside subscribe: keys: " + this.keys + ", values: " + this.values);
    this.getProperties();
}
```

and then I have a method called in the constructor, where Im trying to use those arrays:

```
getProperties() {
    console.log(this.keys);
    console.log(this.values);
}
```

And I'm getting the following output in the console:
[image]

I understand that the subscription is still being executed when `getProperties` is finished already. What I don't know, is how to make `getProperties` wait and then execute with proper data in string arrays. Can someone help me with a solution?
I just need to get that data outside of subscribing somehow, so I can use it in the other method.

Comment: Just move `getProperties` into the subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
keys: string[];
values: string[];

constructor(private entityDetailsService: LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) {
    this.getEntityDetails().subscribe(data => {
        this.keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
        this.values = Object.values(data[0]);
        this.getProperties();
        console.log("inside subscribe: keys: " + this.keys + ", values: " + this.values);
    });
    console.log("outside subscribe: keys: " + this.keys + ", values: " + this.values);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your properties:

```
keys: string[];
values: string[];
```

into Observables:

```
keys$: Observable<string[]>;
values$: Observable<string[]>;
```

your code will then look like that:

```
constructor(private entityDetailsService: LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) {
  const entityDetails$ = this.getEntityDetails().pipe(shareReplay(1));

  this.keys$ = entityDetails$.pipe(map(data => Object.keys(data[0]));
  this.values$ = entityDetails$.pipe(map(data => Object.values(data[0]));
}
```

Then you can use `async` pipe inside your component template:

```
<div>
 {{keys$ | async}}
</div>

<div>
 {{values$ | async}}
</div>

<-- or something like that -->
<child-component-1 [keys]="keys$ | async"></child-component-1>
<child-component-2 [values]="values$ | async"></child-component-2>
```

What is your use case inside template? Depending on that you should also consider changing `keys$` and `values$` into other `Observable`.

For example you could create `data$: Observable<YourObject>`

```
constructor(private entityDetailsService: LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) {
  this.data$ = this.getEntityDetails().pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

and in template use `keyvalue` pipe (https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be managed with Subjects. Something like this (you know, as rule I try avoid http calls in constructor):

```
keys$: Subject<string[]> = new Subject();//<== use Subjects
private _values$: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);//<== or Behaviour Subject

get values(): string[] { return this._values.getValue()}

constructor(private entityDetailsService: LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) {
    this.getEntityDetails().subscribe(data => {
        this.keys.next(Object.keys(data[0]));
        this.values.next(Object.values(data[0]));
    });

    console.log(this.values)// to get current state

    combineLatest(this.keys$, this.values$)
    .subscribe(([keys, values]) => {
       //to get last state
       console.log(keys);
       console.log(values);
    });
}
```